# http headers converted to lowercase in iOS 11

Tags: ios, http-headers, ios11

While testing my iPad application on iOS 11 beta version, I observed a unique behaviour that HTTP headers coming in response are automatically converted to lowercase. How to change this behaviour programmatically? We have checks in code on the actual header name which aren't working with iOS 11 beta since header name is converted to lowercase.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site works best if you include your own code in your question. You can edit you question any time and add additional information. Furthermore, please include the detailed ios version number, perhaps this is a known issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When answering this I assume that the HTTP headers you are talking about are only referring to the key and not the value of the headers.

You could use the `NSString` instance method `-uppercaseString` on the headers in case you want to compare with uppercase strings. It is a smart move to make your code case insensitive in case the server for some reason is edited to send lowercase or mixed case headers in the future.

If iOS is making the value of each header lowercase then that is very bad. I would recommend you to submit a bug report to Apple no matter if the key or the value casing is modified. Maybe you can verify with Charles Web Proxy to see that the response are actually changed.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Regarding the proxy suggestion, I'm seeing lowercased keys when hitting a server directly but capitalized as I set them when going through a proxy. Confirmed via server logs.

Answer (score 3):

Note - the practice of headers being converted to lowercase is in adherence with preparation for the HTTP 2.0 Spec. For HTTP 1.0, headers were supposed to be case-insensitive bot this wasn't always followed. 
See https://evertpot.com/http-2-finalized/

Chrome update 60 already changed so that response headers are now lowercase ( which caused us some problems ! )

It is expected that all the browsers will follow suit with upcoming updates so this is something you need to take care of