# Php Response header getting converted to lower case on https

Tags: php, curl, https, header, response-headers

I have php api call which return some response headers.
When i try to hit the api call with http i get the response header as it is but when i try to do the same thing with https in the url all the response headers get converted to lower case on the ios side.

```
header('X-Session-Id: '.$x_session_id);
```

Resonse Header:

```
x-session-id : "ABCD"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259004/4178487

Comment: @JasonK Not that helpful

Comment: This looks relevant, sounds like something iOS is doing, possibly on purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097898/http-headers-converted-to-lowercase-in-ios-11

Comment: @SameerShaikh How you fixed this issue?